# Whether to drop index before update in sql Server 2000

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005, sql-server-2008-r2, sql-server-2000

It has BEEN UNDERSTOOD THAT THE INDEXES ARE USEFUL for select queries ..

I need to update certain columns in t table from the columns of s table..Both tables consists to millions of rows..So is it good to create index on the **ArrivalYrMonth** and **[Generated Record Identifier]** columns,please see the below query?

**Or** do i need to drop these index before the update?

do i have to drop the index on t.colmn1,t.colmn1,t.colmn1,t.colmn1

```
UPDATE t
SET      t.clmn1=s.clmn1
       , t.clmn2=s.clmn2
       , t.clmn3=s.clmn3
       , t.clmn4=s.clmn4
FROM [AxE_Data] t
INNER JOIN [Tg-DB].[dbo].[AxE_Stg_Data] s
    ON t.[Generated_Record_Identifier] = s.[Generated Record Identifier]
WHERE [ArrivalYrMonth] IN ('201204', '201205', '201206')
```

Please let me know the suggestions ....

Comment: at the momnet there are indexes ,clustered on Generated_Record_Identifier and nonclustered on all other columns.So do i have to drop before the update statement??

Comment: When i ran the query with out droping the indexes the query has been timed out after 3 hours

Comment: You need to tune from the sql estimated execution plan, it is hard to give you suggestion from here. And i don't think is good idea to just drop the index and update. May be the first you need to do is rebuild the index.

Comment: thanks for the sugestion..but the fragmentation is more than 76% so it has to be drop and recreate rt?

Answer (score 0):

You doesnt need to drop it and recreate it. Use these command to rebuild index

```
    DBCC SHOWCONTIG (TABLE_NAME)--To show your table fragmentation 
    DBCC INDEXDEFRAG (0,TABLE_NAME,'INDEXNAME')
    DBCC DBREINDEX (TABLE_NAME, INDXNAME,0 );
```

For more detail , please refer to http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175008.aspx

Comment: Thanks..But what if i drop the clustered index and trying to insert rows then rebuild it?

Comment: i have a clustered index on a primary key column..what id i drop the primary key ..the clustered  index is also going to disappear?

Comment: are you trying to insert or update? for insert if you remove index and insert time can be significantly improve. But for update i don't think it will help much. you need to tune your query or make another version to not update it. For 2nd question, yes if you drop the PK, clustered index will disappear.

Comment: if i remove non clustered index then the insert time can significantly improve? How about droping the clustered index before insertion?is it a recommended way? this post says we should not drop the clustered index before the data insert...http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2013/02/10/sql-server-primary-key-and-nonclustered-index-in-simple-words/

Comment: Well is up to you what you trying to achieve, for me, there is sometimes theory is one thing and performance is another thing. I'm not asking you to believe me but i had experience this too. We have issue on inserting large data (10k+) into table with index but the time taken was too long and is not acceptable, and at the end we have no choice but dropping the index first before insert, it's really improve. When table with no index at all, SQL just do it faster, cause no other work involves. You could try it on your staging before trusting on me. :) Good Luck!

Comment: What if the target table has a primary key? Does it have to disable before the insert operation and enable it after the insert completed?Please let me know,when you are talking about drop index ,does that mean to drop only NON clustered index..or both clustered and non clustered

Comment: It's depend what type of your PK. If it is only a identity column that not affect much as is in order but if your PK is a datetime (bad design) then the speed for sure will slow down as SQL try to re-organize index every time it inserting data.So you should experiment the different. Again, for me, if it is running id, i won't drop it.